Dense subset of $L^1(X)$
Let $(X,\mu)$ be a $\sigma$-finite mearsure space. Suppose $E_1\subset E_2\subset \cdots$ is a sequence of subsets with finite measure such that $X= \cup E_i$.
Let $A = \{ f\in L^1(X): f \text{ is supported in some } E_n\}$. Then I want to show that A is dense in $L^1(X)$.
My idea is to show that every characteristic function $\chi_E$ can be approximated by $A$, $E$ being a finite mearsurable subset. But I need to show that $E$ is contained in some $E_n$, almostly.
I am not sure the last statement is true or not. Can somebody give a hint, thanks very much.

Multiply any $f$ by a suitable characteristic function to show that the result is in $A$.

@copper.hat Thanks. Do I understand your hint correctly: Let $f\in L^1$. Then $f\chi_{E_n}(x)$ converges to $f(x)$ for each $x$. This sequence satisfies the conditon of the dominanted convergence theorem, so $f\chi_{E_n}$ convergence to $f$ in $L^1(X)$.

That is correct.
